# AssertionError : Unable to compare two objects in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

Am using the below functions to fetch value from application and compare it with the expected value.But it's failing with the following outpupt.Please help me resolve this.

```
getEleAttribute = async function(ele, attr) {

    var attribute = await ele.getAttribute(attr);
    return attribute;

}

enterTodayDate= function(){
    return moment(Date.now()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
   }

this.verifyProp = async function () {
   var fetchDate = getEleAttribute(verifyDate, "value").toString().substring(0, 10);
   console.log(fetchDate); // this is printing -- [object Pr
   var today=enterTodayDate().toString();
   assert.equal(fetchDate, today, "Expected Date is not same as Actual Date");

}
```

Output :

```
AssertionError: Expected Date is not same as Actual Date: expected '[object Pr' to equal '2020-06-18'
           + expected - actual

           -[object Pr
           +2020-06-18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved after the below changes :

```
var fetchDate = getEleAttribute(verifyDate, "value");
var actualDate= String(fetchDate).substr(0, 10);
console.log(actualDate); //printed -- 2020-06-19
```

Answer (score 1):

The codes seems fine but there is something wrong in your logic.

The call `getEleAttribute(verifyDate, "value").toString()` is returning an the object's name instead of a string with date in it. The assert fails when you compare it with the date string generated using the `moment` method.

You need to debug the code and see what the `getEleAttribute` function returns.

Comment: Issue is with the substring(0,10). It's fetching the correct value but using substring it is printing [object pr